# Why is a "Semi-leptonic" Decay Mode called so?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, terminology, leptons

Why is a [semileptonic decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semileptonic_decay) mode called so?

I mean, if there is one lepton amongst the decay products, it should be leptonic, right?

If there are two, that should be called bi-leptonic or something like that?

Why is the former called a semileptonic mode, and the latter called leptonic?

What is this "*semi*" in semileptonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking the prefix *semi* means *half*, but it's often used in the sense of *partial*. A good example of this would be *semiconductor*.

So *semileptonic* just means *partially leptonic*.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I get this correctly, you mean semileptonic decay is that decay where you have a non-lepton + a lepton as products, and leptonic decay is that one where the products are exclusively lepton(s), i.e. no non-leptons?

Comment: @UserAnonymous: yes, that's my interpretation.

Comment: yes that seems to make a lot of sense. Thanks again.